# Does Docker collect data processed by the container (Docker Desktop)

Tags: docker, docker-container, privacy-policy

I am going to use Azures Computer Vision (Read 3.2) and run it on-premise as a container, and therefore using Docker Desktop.

However, I have not been able to figure out if Docker collects any data that is being processed by containers running on Docker.
In https://www.docker.com/legal/security-and-privacy-guidelines under the header 'Data Privacy and Security' Docker writes:

"In general, Docker does not collect or store personal data and the use of Docker products does not result in personal data being collected or stored."

Now, to me, this sounds ambiguous. We are using Azure's on-premise container in order to stay compliant and that part works since Azure does not collect any data from the container. However, if Docker itself collects data then that is a show stopper. FYI, I am a beginner to Docker and I might be completely off.

EDIT: So my question is, does Docker collect any of the input or the output going in and out from the container?

Thankful for any answers or wisdom you might be able to share.

Regards

Comment: Your question seems to be does Docker collect the stdout/stderr output of a running container? I do not think docker collects anything from a running container. The docker desktop running a container might collect stats on containers executed, etc. but they do not collect the 'output' of a running container.

Comment: @johnXF I apologize for not stating a clear-cut question, it slipped my mind. You assumed correctly and I thank you for your answer.

Comment: Thanks, I'll post a proper reply that you can accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you saw, the [Docker privacy policy](https://www.docker.com/legal/docker-privacy-policy) "applies to Docker websites, products and services offered by Docker". I do not think running a Docker image as a container would be considered under those terms, and so I do not think Docker collect any information produced by the container as 'output' - i.e. standard output/error streams or the like.

Docker Desktop may collect statistics, metrics and information on the images/containers run directly under Docker desktop where they have access to that information, but also many docker-built images will be run under non-docker environments (such as Kubernetes) where they could not have access to the such information.

As an aside, I think all the image themselves be built from scratch and you (or other interested parties) have access to the layers within the image so you can see what has been added and what the effect of the layer is. Thus you could also verify that Docker (or other parties) are not harvesting data from a running container.